# Nuxt Cannot find module @nuxt/ufo from /app/cilent. No changes were made

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I have a docker image running a nuxt application that i restarted today and with no other changes being made other than the restart i am now getting this error ...

ERROR  Cannot find module '@nuxt/ufo' from '/app/client'

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here. Manually installing `@nuxt/ufo` solves the problem:

```
npm install @nuxt/ufo
```

If your docker is based on `node:12-buster`, you can login into the instance and run the command there (using `docker exec -it <docker process> bash`). It will fix the issue for now.

The permanent solution is to add `@nuxt/ufo`to `package.json` and recreate your docker image.

```
"@nuxt/ufo": "^0.5.4",
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the /node_modules folder, and install the modules again

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, I was using pnpm to install dependency. Changed to npm worked like a charm. Delete node_modules/ and any .lock file created by other package manager. Also if using nuxt2+ its better if you use node v14 for some reason most of the dependencies are in the edge of deprecation. This means nuxt wants everyone to migrate to nuxt3 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Error can be by requiring "ufo" npm package.

Try it if above solution don't work:

https://github.com/unjs/ufo#readme

> npm i ufo --save

(it's old @nuxt/ufo package)