# Nuxt deployment to Azure - cannot find module @nuxt/ufo

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js

I am deploying the Nuxt application to Azure, and have recently upgraded to the latest version of nuxt. It runs locally, but when deploying to azure I receive:

[image: Azure server error]

My understanding was that this module was removed in 2.15.x. I have removed all files (rm -r -d *) from the azure app's wwwroot folder and deployed fresh from Visual Studio Code.

```
Starting deployment...
Creating zip package...
Zip package size: 53.6 MB
Fetching changes.
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extract
-ce0578fcc258.zip (51.17 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id 'd3a896856e'.
Generating deployment script.
Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no
te/deployments/tools" --basic --sitePath "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running deployment command...
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
Kudu sync from: '/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted' to: '/home/site/wwwroot
Copying file: 'App.vue'
Copying file: 'ecosystem.config.js'
Copying file: 'main.js'
Copying file: 'nuxt.config.js'
Copying file: 'package-lock.json'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'sources.info'
Copying file: 'test.env'
Ignoring: .deployment
Copying file: '.nuxt/App.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/auth.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/axios.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/client.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/cookie-universal-nuxt.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/empty.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/index.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/jsonp.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/loading.html'
Copying file: '.nuxt/middleware.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/router.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/router.scrollBehavior.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/routes.json'
Copying file: '.nuxt/server.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/store.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/utils.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/index.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-build-indicator.vue'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-child.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.server.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/nuxt.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/plugin.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/components/readme.md'
Copying file: '.nuxt/mixins/fetch.client.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/mixins/fetch.server.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/vetur/tags.json'
Copying file: '.nuxt/views/app.template.html'
Copying file: '.nuxt/views/error.html'
Copying file: '.nuxt/vuetify/options.js'
Copying file: '.nuxt/vuetify/plugin.js'
Copying file: 'assets/README.md'
Copying file: 'assets/logo.png'
Copying file: 'assets/variables.scss'
Copying file: 'assets/images/accessibility.jpg'
Copying file: 'assets/images/collaboration.jpg'
Omitting next output lines...
Processed 1160 files...
Processed 2537 files...
Processed 3971 files...
Processed 4957 files...
Processed 6169 files...
Processed 7610 files...
Processed 9345 files...
Processed 10695 files...
Processed 12066 files...
Processed 13778 files...
Processed 15096 files...
Processed 16553 files...
Processed 18211 files...
Processed 19594 files...
Processed 20928 files...
Processed 22606 files...
Processed 24410 files...
Processed 25672 files...
Processed 26666 files...
Processed 27857 files...
Processed 29085 files...
Finished successfully.
Running post deployment command(s)...
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful.
completed.
```

I am unsure why this module is required, if it was removed. There is no @nuxt/ufo folder locally (where it runs OK locally)

Package json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore . --fix",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.5",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "^5.0.0-1610642462.1bcdc1e",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "qrcode.vue": "^1.7.0",
    "vue-auth-image": "0.0.3",
    "vue-draggable-resizable": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-wordcloud": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
```

Any other places to look or things to try?

**UPDATE 1**

So, I added the deprecated package to the package.json file and re-deployed. This has then highlighted an underlying issue. The content is still from an older version, however, looking in KUDO I can see the new content there, but yet the site is serving up an old one. If I stop the site in Azure, it does stop working, so definitely in the right app etc). This probably explains the ufo issue, because if it is still the old code, then it will be on nuxt 1.14.6 and still referencing the deprecated @nuxt/ufo module.

Comment: Do you use `@nuxt/ufo` somewhere in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: I do not think so, but I assume it must be being used somewhere to want to use it. I might spin up a new nuxt app and see what references it includes by default

Answer (score 0):

From [what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826795/8816585), installing the package with `npm i @nuxt/ufo` should fix it.

More details on the package itself [available here](https://github.com/unjs/ufo#readme).

Maybe cleaning up your node_modules and trying to double-check if every dependency is resolved, may help too.

Comment: I am sure it would, but the point is that the package is deprecated, so don't really want to use it when the point of the task it so upgrade packages.

Comment: @Simon where do you see that this is deprecated?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/ufo